# cURL: curl: (18) transfer closed with 96671047906 bytes remaining to read

Tags: ubuntu, download, curl

I am trying to download a very massive file (~92Gb) using *cURL*:

```
curl -L -o 'file.tar.gz' -C - http://abc.dummy/file.tar.gz
```

and constantly getting into:

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with ... bytes remaining to read
```

which quits *cURL* leaving file partially downloaded.

How to ask *cURL* to resume transfer until download is complete?

**P.S.** It seems the error occurs after ~1Gb chunk has been downloaded.

Comment: You may find the last answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19728930/3395469) useful.